# Confused about this & getcontext js/ts and how to get around it

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-2017

So, i have a problem where i'm constantly running into undifined errors, (in browser) and seemingly can't figure out why / how to get around it. From what i've gathered is that the keyword "this" is an utterly confusing mess in js & inherently in ts too.

Here is my problme:

```
export class XY
{
   property: boolean;
    //other proprs
   constructor()
    {this.property = false;}

 setproperty(e) //this is an onclick event
 {
  this.property = true;
 //my problem is that this.property doesn't refer to class member variable "property"
 }
}
```

even if i try something like
const boundGet = XY.bind.(xy), it still undefined and "unreachable"

if not with the keyword "this", how am i supposed to refer to member variable property without making it const??

Comment: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: i'll read both and update, thanks!

Comment: The issue here is that you're not correctly initializing the instance member in the constructor. Should be: `constructor() { this.property = false; }`

Comment: made an edit. I do i my code, just copied it improperly, to stack overflow lol.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the problem was with Devextreme's event binding.
If you want to override their datagrids controls "edit" buttons event, you have to pass the event like this [onClick]="yourfunc" now that's obviously not the standard (event)="blabla".
Whatever happens in the background messes up the context for "this".
went around the problem by using a different event.